# Nextjs Image Cache Invalidation

Tags: amazon-s3, next.js, frontend, backend

I'm using aws s3 buckets to store my assets. When any of the existed assets is changed from the front-end (eg: client changed his profile image) the backend I made will change the asset only without touching the url. Now here is my problem in my website I'm using **revalidate** in **getStaticProps** but still because the link is the same, the cached version of the image is not updating so any way to update those images caches programmatically?

By the way when I click on DevTools and see the preview from the Network tab it shows the right version of the asset

Comment: There's no built-in way to invalidate `next/image` cache, but you could configure the `Cache-Control` header on the upstream image to reduce its max-age. See https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#minimum-cache-ttl.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you add a timestamp to your image url as a query parameter it works with client side rendering. Not sure about server side rendering tho. Give it a try.

```
const url = 'http://someHost.someBucket.someImageName.jpeg'
const timeStamp = new Date().getTime()
<img src={`${url}?${timestamp}`} />
```

Answer (score 1):

Going off of Nazrul's answer, I came up with the following to optimize for my situation (and using the Next Image component):

```
const media = { 
  url: 'http://someHost.someBucket.someImageName.jpeg',
  id: '123456789'
}
<Image src={`${media.url}?${media.id}`} />
```

I'm using this in a page that is user updatable and I was often getting a loader for my image when it didn't actually need to be re-cached if I used the timestamp option. For me, using the id (which only changes if the media is completely new) worked to reduce the amount of times it was re-cached.

Comment: That's perfect actually since the id will change whenever you change the image it will lead to other URL which will not use the cached one

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a `CloudFront` distribution to serve the images from the `S3` bucket, you'll need to invalidate the cache in `CloudFront`. Head to

`CloudFront > Distributions > [YOUR DISTRIBUTION] > Invalidations`

Select `Create invalidation` and enter the path to the image you want to invalidate. To invalidate all images, for example, use `/*`. See [CloudFront docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html) for more.